# Memory leak in Google sparse_hash_map

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, memory-leaks, sparsehash

This week I've been trying to spot an unusual memory behavior: when I run my code with one single thread I have a specific memory footprint, but if I run it with multiple threads then the memory footprint increases a lot with no apparent reason.

I know strange things can happen due to the indeterministic nature of a multithreaded program, so some deterministic approach is better used to debug this. However, even in a such very deterministic situation I failed to see why the memory footprint increases.

Here's the smallest program I've been able to write that reproduce the problem:

## test.cpp

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <sparsehash/sparse_hash_map>
#include <thread>

struct mystruct
{
    uint64_t values[16];
    inline bool operator==(const mystruct &other) const {
        return !memcmp(values, other.values, sizeof(values));
    }
    inline bool operator!=(const mystruct &other) const { 
        return !(*this == other); 
    }
};

namespace std {
    template<>
    class hash<mystruct> {
    public:
        inline size_t operator()(const mystruct &s) const 
        {
            return s.values[0];
        }
    };
}

google::sparse_hash_map<mystruct, uint64_t, std::hash<mystruct>> h;

const uint64_t N = 1ull * 1024ull * 1024ull * 1024ull;
const int step = 128;
volatile uint64_t next = 0;
uint64_t total_keys = 0;
const uint64_t THREADS = 1;

void insert_data(uint64_t data) {
    unsigned char buf[256];
    mystruct b;
    for (uint64_t j = 0; j < N / THREADS; j++) {
        SHA256((unsigned char*)&data, 8, buf);
        memcpy(&b, buf, sizeof(mystruct));

        while (next != data)
            ;

        h[b] = 1;
        total_keys++;
        next += step;
        data += THREADS * step;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t[THREADS];

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
        t[i] = std::thread(insert_data, i * step);
    }   

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    while (total_keys < N) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        uint64_t elapsed_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count();
        double speed = 1000.0*(double)total_keys / (double)elapsed_ms ;

        std::cout << std::fixed << "Processed " << total_keys << " items in " << elapsed_ms << " ms (" << std::setprecision(0) << speed << " keys/s)"  << ", next key is " << next << std::endl;
    }

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
        t[i].join();
    }
}
```

The idea of the program is dead simple:

- Insert a **known and predetermined sequence** of 1 gazillion keys into the hashtable with a loop
- Watch the program dumping every 100ms on the console how many keys it inserted so far, and what's the next key that is going to be inserted
- Wait until the OS kills the program

So, the goal is to verify that for a predefined sequence of inserts the memory consumption is the same *regardless of how many threads push the data into the hashtable*, that is the number of inserted keys is roughly the same (I don't mind if there's a few keys of differences, eg due to OS deciding to kill the application). Well the difference can be huge.

The `insert_data` function uses a simple spin loop to guarantee the insertion sequence, that is the numbers 0, 128, 256, and so on... (using a lock/mutex makes no differences).

I ran the program in the following environment:

- A Debian 8.3 Linux VM with 4GB of RAM
- No swap memory with *swapoff -a*
- GCC 4.9.2 with `-O3` flag

and these are the results when the above code runs with different number of the **THREADS** variable:

## THREADS = 1

```
Processed 54241 items in 100 ms (542410 keys/s), next key is 6942848
Processed 104857 items in 200 ms (524285 keys/s), next key is 13421696
...
Processed 13410458 items in 35698 ms (375664 keys/s), next key is 1716538624
Processed 13421773 items in 35799 ms (374920 keys/s), next key is 1717986944
...
... 6 seconds of data because hashtable is being resized...
...
Processed 13421773 items in 41245 ms (325416 keys/s), next key is 1717986944
Processed 13438143 items in 41345 ms (325025 keys/s), next key is 1720082432
...
Processed 23580346 items in 65567 ms (359637 keys/s), next key is 3018284416
Killed
```

## THREADS = 2

```
Processed 69922 items in 101 ms (692297 keys/s), next key is 8950016
Processed 121766 items in 202 ms (602802 keys/s), next key is 15586048
...
Processed 13409271 items in 37098 ms (361455 keys/s), next key is 1716386688
Processed 13421773 items in 37198 ms (360820 keys/s), next key is 1717986944
...
... 6 seconds of data because hashtable is being resized...
...
Processed 13421773 items in 43204 ms (310660 keys/s), next key is 1717986944
Processed 13443021 items in 43304 ms (310434 keys/s), next key is 1720706688
...
Processed 20024294 items in 64129 ms (312250 keys/s), next key is 2563110656
Killed
```

## THREADS = 4

```
Processed 31 items in 100 ms (310 keys/s), next key is 3968
Processed 33882 items in 200 ms (169410 keys/s), next key is 4336896
...
Processed 13399262 items in 48949 ms (273739 keys/s), next key is 1715105536
Processed 13421773 items in 49049 ms (273640 keys/s), next key is 1717986944
...
... 5 seconds of data because hashtable is being resized...
...
Processed 13421773 items in 54091 ms (248133 keys/s), next key is 1717986944
Processed 13421773 items in 54201 ms (247630 keys/s), next key is 1717986944
Killed
```

As you can see, all three tests identified the particular key `1717986944` as the key that triggers the hashtable resize, and all of them happen at the same inserted key n.`13421773`, and this confirms that the inserts always happen strictly in the same order regardless of the number of running threads.

However, the **THREADS=1** inserted 3556052 more keys (corresponding to 434MB) than **THREADS=2**, and inserted 6602521 more keys (corresponding to 805MB) than **THREADS=4**.

Can anyone explain me why I have a such weird memory consumption even in such deterministic conditions? Is there something that I'm actually missing?

Comment: You write to `total_keys` in a non-threadsafe way by several threads at the same time. It will give you wrong numbers

Comment: Same for `next`. Do you expect `volatile` to provide atomicity?

Comment: I could not find a statement about the Thread-safety of sparse hashmap, so I tend to say that it is not thread-safe as well.

Comment: @RustyX no I expect the compiler not to cache `next` in registers and to force memory order. And it works because it is accessed only from the thread inserting the key. Other threads are still waiting in the loop.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have forced a memory order with the `volatile` on the `next`. Changing to std::atomic or adding a lock/mutex just doesn't change the results as I said early. I read mutex had a memory leak on GCC 4.9 branch and I simply wanted to exclude that leak in this test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as an answer since I was able to understand what's going on.

After a good amount of time and debugging I found out that the root cause of the memory consumption is a pathological memory alloc/dealloc pattern that produces heap fragmentation. No memory leaks or whatsoever. I was able to reproduce the problem with a custom hashtable implementation too.

As weird as it is, in both cases adding a `malloc_trim(0);` at the end of the main loop just after the line

```
std::cout << std::fixed << "Processed " << total_keys << " items in " << elapsed_ms << " ms (" << std::setprecision(0) << speed << " keys/s)"  << ", next key is " << next << std::endl;
```

compensates a bit and allows the program to reclaim more memory.